# Dart splits long stdout data into two ProcessResult events

Tags: process, dart

When listening to a long string output from a shell process, I receive the data in two chunks. How can I get the entire text?

Here is the code in question:

```dart
int i = 0;
Process.start('perl', ['print_text.pl']).then((Process p) {
  p.stdout.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((data) => print("${i++} ${data}"));
  p.stdin.writeln('print');
});
```

The result from running this code is:

> 0 text.....
>
> 1 text.....

I've reported this issue as a bug [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/22440). You can run the sample app attached to the report to see the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to process the file in some other JSON tool? Does the FormatException provide more details? I guess you should create an issue at http://dartbug.com/new

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added the stack trace to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Because the stdout result is very long the rest of the code execute before the result is fully loaded. Then, JSON.decode ends up decoding an incomplete json string. Should not Process.run() return complete results?

Comment: Seems more related to Process.run() than JSON.decode(). Can you please add some code that demonstrates what's going on?

Comment: Turned out the process result is being split and sent separately back to stdout listener.

Comment: I don't understand what your last comment means. Could you fix it?

Comment: Ok. the result from running my shell script is not being sent in one ProcessResult event. But, it is split into two shorter strings and sent in two ProcessResult events. Therefore, JSON.decode is receiving incomplete json strings.

Comment: I don't think this is a dart problem. The shell appears to be splitting my data for some reason.

Comment: What's the problem of adding the data of more than one event to a stream or combining them in some other way?

Comment: I retract my last comment. The shell is actually displaying my data as one string. But Dart is splitting it. @GünterZöchbauer I'm starting a shell process with Process.start() and sending process request with stdin.write(). I'll try to combine the data from the multiple events.

Comment: Can you please add the code to the question. Without actual code that shows what you're doing the discussion is rather pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [UTF8.decodeStream()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:convert.Utf8Codec#id_decodeStream).

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert' show UTF8;

main() {
  Process.start('ls', ['-la'])
    .then((p) => UTF8.decodeStream(p.stdout))
    .then((s) => print('Output:\n$s'));
}
```

Comment: This solution only retrieve the initial output from starting the process. It does not listen to subsequent process results.

Comment: This code will wait for the process to terminate and return all of the output as a string. If this isn't what you want, then update the question to explain what you are trying to achieve in more detail. It sounds like you need to add some sort of delimiter character to your output, and to split on that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by doing the following:

1. In the shell script, tag the start and the end of the shell's output with a random number.
2. In Dart, concatenate all the chunks together and use the tags to check if you got the complete result.

This solution does not require exiting the process to obtain the process result.

This is a sample code:

```dart
 String text = '';
 process.stdout.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((String chunk) { 
      text = text + chunk;
      if (text.substring(errors.length - 1) == text.substring(0, 1)) {
           text = text.replaceFirst(new RegExp(r'^(\d+)'), '').replaceFirst(new RegExp(r'(\d+)$'), '');
           // use process result then clear text value for subsequent process results
           text = '';
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the actual question is but I assume this is what you are looking for:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert' show UTF8;

void main() {
  int i = 0;
  String text = '';
  Process.start('perl', ['analyze.pl']).then((p) {
    p.stdout.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((data) =>
      text += data);
    p.exitCode.then((_) => print(text));
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm using analyze.pl as a background process that will receive many distinctive process requests. But, your solution will combine unrelated process results. I could have used Process.run() if I wanted to start a the shell process for each request and quit after receiving the results. But, I want to keep the shell process running in the background and ready for process requests. The root of the problem is that dart unnecessarily splits process results. I'll report this issue as you've suggested earlier.

Comment: Actually with the current information I don't think there is an issue. See for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer. You just have to find a way to cope with the chunks.

Comment: I have reported the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22440&thanks=22440&ts=1424114442

Comment: This is not a bug. Writes to stdout will get split if they are big. Your code needs to deal with this.

Comment: Also note it is the event handler to stdout.listen() that is being called multiple times.  This bit is only called once: .then((Process) { ... })

Comment: @GregLowe Thank you for explaining this. I wish Dart offers a way to track these chunked results.